# having problems getting single item out of array every second in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to loop through some items, for this i made a simple example to test: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

I also have to following code written:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            const doubled = numbers.map((number) => number * 2);
            console.log(doubled);
        }, 3000)
    }, [])
```

this gives me the following output 1,2,3,4,5 every 3 seconds in the concole log.
But what i want to achieve is: show 1 -> wait 3 seconds -> show 2 -> wait 3 seconds -> show 4 etc

What is the best way to get this output ?

Comment: You'll need to maintain a count of the index somewhere. I also suggest using [`useInterval`](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) because using `setInterval` in an effect can cause unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `index` state and use the `useEffect` hook to simply update the index. Use a second `useEffect` hook to access the `numbers` array and compute a double. Note the second effect takes the index modulus the numbers array length so the index is always in range.

***Note:** Don't forget to clear the interval when the component unmounts!*

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex((i) => i + 1);
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const doubled = numbers[index % numbers.length] * 2;
    console.log(doubled);
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Edit to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a school example use case for a generator. Something among the lines of the following should work:

```
function *test() {
  const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
  let idx=0
  while (idx < numbers.length){
    yield numbers[idx]
    idx++
  }
}

let gen = test()
setInterval( () => console.log(gen.next().value), 1000)
```

You just need to add some check for the `done` value of the generator.

Comment: While I do like the idea of using a generator function, I'm not sure how well this would fit in in a React component that needs a state/props update to trigger a rerender. Although, an initial render would start the interval and the callback could console log each yielded value independently of the component lifecycle.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the React-part of the question. I cannot anser this point, as I am missing the necessary React-skills.